# Custom actions and cache the ScriptSrc path

Tags: development, custom-actions, cache

I created custom actions from ribbon via this article - [Deploying Custom Action to specific lists in SharePoint 2010](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/3a164c/deploying-custom-action-to-specific-lists-in-sharepoint-2010/) - which works fine.

But when I created a new project I copied from my last project and forgot to change path for the JS file, and deployed the project.

```
var scriptlink = site.UserCustomActions.Add();
scriptlink.Location = "ScriptLink";
scriptlink.ScriptSrc = "/_layouts/15/SharePointProject2/JavaScript2.js";
scriptlink.Update();
```

Now if I correct the path to the JS file SharePoint still tries to loads the script from the old path.

I have tried reseting IIS, but still SP gets the wrong file.

What can I do in future when I have that problem? I assume it is some cache but I don't know what delete and where.

I use SP2013 and VS 2013

Answer (score 0):

Try this(CSOM):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string siteUrl = "http://sp:12001";

            ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
            Web site = clientContext.Web;

            UserCustomActionCollection collUCA = site.UserCustomActions;
            clientContext.Load(collUCA, cas => cas.Where(ca => ca.Title == "myScript"));
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            if(collUCA.Count<1){
                UserCustomAction scriptlink = collUCA.Add();
                scriptlink.Location = "ScriptLink";
                scriptlink.Title = "myScript";
                scriptlink.ScriptSrc = "/_layouts/15/js/JavaScript1.js";               
                scriptlink.Update();

                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            }
            else
            {
                UserCustomAction scriptlink = collUCA.First();
                scriptlink.ScriptSrc = "/_layouts/15/js/JavaScript2.js";
                scriptlink.Update();
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            }



            Console.WriteLine("done");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but i deploy it as site features so with my knowledge i dont know how in this case use your code.
But finally i found mistake - i can't use this same name of js functions like my another features.